# How to create a timeline of infected hosts from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, security, metrics

I am attempting to plot (either with R or Python) a timeline of outbreaks that shows that on X date X host was infected. I have a CSV file that contains three columns: `["MD5", "Hostname", "Time"]`; the time is in a "%Y-%m-%d" format. I know for this example MD5 perhaps might not be used, but it is included as a field-column in the CSV.

Below is an example of a bar chart I was able to get working using the data within my CSV file, but what its showing is the number of counts (alert frequency of the infection) per user. How might I be able to relate this to show a timeline?

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')
pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center')   # FOR TABLE <th>

data = "/Users/john/Desktop/file.csv"

data_plot = pd.read_csv(data) # av 

data_plot.columns = ["MD5", "Hostname", "Time"]

#print(data_plot)
#print(result)

host_ct = pd.value_counts(data_plot['Hostname'])

plt.axes(frameon=0)
host_ct.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, title="Summary by Host", figsize=(8,5)).grid(False)
# print(host_ct)

html_string = '''
<html>
  <head><title>HTML Pandas Dataframe with CSS</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    {table}
  </body>
</html>.
'''

with open('myhtml.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_string.format(table=data_plot.to_html()))

# HTML(data_plot.head(30).to_html())
```

Here is an out put of data_plot.head:

```
MD5    Hostname                Time
hash   Macbook-001.001.LOCAL   2018-12-07
hash   Macbook-002.002.LOCAL   2018-12-08
hash   Macbook-003.003.LOCAL   2018-12-09
```

I would like a timeline showing the first date of infection (and on which host) to the last date of infection (and again including which host).

Comment: Could you add to your question some sample CSV input and also a sample output?

Comment: What do you want to plot on the y-axis? Cumulative infections? Number of hosts infected at that timestamp? Do you want separate lines for each MD5?  As written, is Pandas parsing the time data into datetime values or strings?  It isn't real clear what you need help with?  Some example data would help us - like `data_plot.head(10)`.

Comment: I have since edited my question to be more specific; hope that's better!

Comment: Hello again, I have added sample output which the sample input is in .CSV format. The hostnames and dates are in the format above.